# python dataframe scatter plot: draw line between value from same row

Tags: python, dataframe, hyperlink, line, scatter

I managed to show two scatter plots from the same dataframe on one figure and try to link the point from the same row with a line on the figure. By any chance anyone might have an idea how i can do it? Thanks.

```
ax = pldata.plot(kind='scatter', x='column1', y='column2', 
    c='DarkBlue', label='Left', s=25)
pldata.plot(kind='scatter', x='column3', y='column4', c='DarkGreen', 
    label='Right', s=25, ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide an example of your data so I made a reproducible example for you.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20, 4), columns=['x', 'y', 'xx', 'yy'])
print(df)
```

```py
Out[31]: 
          x         y        xx        yy
0  0.362230  0.678728  0.905515  0.236933
1  0.998008  0.613584  0.425929  0.133023
2  0.236703  0.742487  0.812784  0.237387
3  0.833180  0.417141  0.503885  0.560123
4  0.193055  0.474450  0.249819  0.716194
```

Here's the original scatterplot:

```py
plt.scatter(df.x, df.y)
plt.scatter(df.xx, df.yy)
```

And here are the lines between them:

```py
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    a, b, c, d = zip(df.iloc[i, :])
    plt.plot([a, c], [b, d], c='black', alpha=.3)
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. __If you want to say "thank you," vote and accept that person's answer__. _READ_: [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).